# when swipe pivot quickly the pivot performance slowly

Tags: windows-phone-7, pivot, panorama-control

there

I found that when quickly swiping or flicking the pivot, the pivot will become very obtuse.When the finger off the screen the pivot still traslate between pivotItems a few times.
Is there any way to make the Pivot performance like the Panorama in the situation of quickly swiping or flicking.

Comment: What do you do in each pivot item? Do you do any IO operation? Make a blank pivot project from the template and compare performance.

Comment: I just want to how to prevent the Pivot to Transform many times when I stop swipe or flick.But the Panorama won't like that.

Comment: What you can do is to customize or build your own Pivot. Here is source code that may help you http://phone.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/55041#824017

Comment: I already have the the code which Lukas mentioned.Somehow the code is not the exactly Pivot source code.There is still some diffenrence.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem which was due to using more than 5 tabs each with databinding on them. Each time I swerved to a new page the databinding was triggered thus causing a noticeable delay. (If you keep swirving these requests create a backfill this eventually resulting in multiple background threads for each pivot tab)

I fixed this by collapsing the data on the tabs and only revealing it when the tab was shown for more than 3 seconds. This greatly reduced the databinding and thus data loading. Inmy case though I did have to resort to this because I used the tabs as ways to navigate through dates thus I was facing a potentially limitless collection and had to cycle data across my 5 available tabs. (Microsoft recommends against using more than 5 tabs).

If you have a finite set of less than 6 tabs an easier approach would be to set data binding to ‘one time’ to populate the data. If you have items on the tabs that rely on allowing a control to not just display but also update a value you can always trigger the databinding through that controls events. (be sure to not just use the updated method but also the page.navigateaway event to trigger databinding as navigating away from a page right after updating the value of a control won’t trigger the control.updated event)